# How can I change the face color of my obj files?

Tags: colors, three.js, vertex

This code create a 3d object in a canvas with Three.js library. I want to color a vertices or the faces of my geometry saved in a json file.

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var callbackMale = function (geometry, materials) {
    // the face's indices are labeled with these characters 
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var faceIndices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
        var face = geometry.faces[i];
        // determine if face is a tri or a quad
        var numberOfSides = (face instanceof THREE.Face3) ? 3 : 4;
        // assign color to each vertex of current face
        for (var j = 0; j < numberOfSides; j++) {
            var vertexIndex = face[faceIndices[j]];
            // initialize color variable
            var color = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
            color.setRGB(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random());
            face.vertexColors[j] = color;
        }
        geometry.dynamic = true;
        geometry.needsUpdate = true;
        createScene(geometry, materials, 90, FLOOR, 50, 105)
    }
}; // fine callBack
loader.load("brain.js", callbackMale);
```

Comment: You understand that you will be overriding colors by this method.

Comment: Have you set material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors}); (as per the example misc_controls_pointerlock.html)

Comment: You should give credit if the answer is correct. Thank you.

Comment: thank you @gaitat for your answer. I don't know how can i give you credit ?

Comment: on the left of the answer, there is an up-arrow.